# Does EF automatically load many to many references collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, cartesian-product

Imagine we have the following db structure

```
 Organization 
 {
    Guid OrganizationId
    //....
 }

 User 
 {
    Guid UserId
 }

 OrganizationUsers
 {
     Guid OrganizationId
     Guid UserId 
 }
```

When the edmx generated this class it abstracts away the `OrganizationUsers` into a many to many references.  So no POCO class will be generated for it.

Say I'm loading data from my context, but to avoid Cartesian Production, I don't use an include I make two seperate queries.

```
using(var context = new EntitiesContext())
{
    var organizationsQuery =  context.Where(FilterByParent);
    var organizations = organizationsQuery.ToList();
    var users = organizationsQuery.SelectMany(x => x.Users).Load();
}
```

Is it safe to assume that the connected entitites are loaded?
Would this make any difference if I loaded the users directly from the DBSet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From database point of view:

> Is it safe to assume that the connected entitites are loaded?

Yes It's safe, because first `organizations` being tracked by `EF Change Tracker` and then by calling `Load` in next statement EF knows that results should be attach to tracked entities

> Would this make any difference if I loaded the users directly from the DBSet?

In fact using `Load` this way does nothing better than `Include`!

If you use `Include` EF translate it to `LEFT JOIN`, if you use `Load` it will be translated to `INNER JOIN`, and if you fetch Users directly by their ids using `Contains` method it will be translated to `IN` on Sql side.
In `Load` and `Contains` cases you execute two query (in two pass) on Sql, but in `Include` case it's being done in one pass, so overally it's outperform your approach.

You can compare these approaches yourself using `Sql Profiler` tool.

---

**Update**:

Based on conversations I realized that the main issue of Johnny is just existence of `OrganizationUsers` object. So I suggest to change your approach from `DB First` to `Code first` then this object explicitly could be exist! See [this](https://github.com/sjh37/EntityFramework-Reverse-POCO-Code-First-Generator) to help you on this way

Also another approach that I guess maybe work is customizing `T4 Template` that seems harder but not impossible!

Comment: so entity framework will always load intermediary tables without explicit specifications in the include?

Comment: @johnny5 EF translate your `Include` to some joins and apply your filters as `WHERE` clauses on it and select (in your case) all `Users` of your filtered `organizations`. all these will be done on Sql side, not in your application. Then resulted Users with their OrganizationIds will be loaded in your application and grouped based on their OrganizationsId and attach to your Organizations objects.

Comment: Sorry I'm still a bit confused,  I Just want to make sure we're on the same page.  `Users` don't have an `organizationId`, Nor does `organization` have a `userid`. They are only connected by the intermediary table `UserInOrganizations`.   So If I load the `users`, and then In another query I load the `Organizations`, at which point are the `UsersInOrganizations` Loaded? The first query, second or both?

Comment: @johnny5 Let return to your sample code in your question, both of `OrganizationUsers` and `Users` will be loaded only when `organizationsQuery.SelectMany(x => x.Users).Load();` is executed

Comment: I'm afraid after testing this is not the case,  EntityFramework will not load associated tables from a select many,  I think in this case you are overlooking the intermediary table (OrganizationUsers).  Select only selects an object and not the  connection between the references.

Comment: @johnny5: So I realized we had different point of views to this problem. My focus was on Sql side and data which fetched from database, here are relations also loaded? the answer is Yes, relations also loaded and necessary for grouping users per organizations. But will these relations also attached to relation objects? probably not! my focuse was on amount of data that will fetch (and its performance impact) As I mentioned in last line my focus was on comparing different approaches based on their sql profile and performance

Comment: Yeah, I'm still trying to figure out how to do it, otherwise I'll just have to take a performance and network hit

Comment: @johnny5 If your issue is just existance of `OrganizationUsers` I suggest to change your approach to `Code first` then this object explicitely could be exist!

Comment: I agree.  If you update your answer to reflect that this will can only work through code first I'll mark as correct again